# Activate dropdown with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have a pure HTML CSS navigation bar with some dropdowns. However on ipad the hover will obviously not work.

I want to add a click event to the relevant menu items so the dropdown will also activate with an onclick event.

I've look at other answers but I'm not capable of reading javascript well enough so that I can modify them for my specific site.

here is a link to where I'm at now: http://2ftrade.nl/kareem/eindopdracht/

and this is the relevant html. In my css the default is display:none for the dropdown menus  and is changed to display:block when hovered over the li that contains it.

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href=" " title="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a title="">Opleiding</a> 

                <!-- the dropdown -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Visie &amp; Beleid</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Opbouw Studieprogramma</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Competenties</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Diploma</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Beroepen</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Onderwijsprogramma</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Organisatie</a></li>
            <li><a title="">Stages en Projecten</a>

                <!-- another dropdown -->
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Stages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Projecten</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#home">Top</a></li>
        </ul>
```

This is the css that hides the dropdown section

```
nav > ul > li > ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

and this is what will display it when hovering

```
 nav > ul > li:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: post current code used for menu. Should not expect people to go to a full page and try to find it

Comment: I'm sorry, I honestly thought this was sufficient as I'm not looking for a css solution. my apologies. 1 sec I'll add the relevant css that hides and displays the dropdown.

Comment: For the record, there is no JavaScript based navigation on your site. It works just per CSS.

Comment: Oh I know sven, I intend to add some javascript so I can change the style of an html element onclick, rather than by hover which is what it does now. (it seems that I'm not so good at the proper question ettiquette, my bad).

Answer (score 1):

you can attach event listener to your element:

```
var dropdown_button = document.getElementById('#your-button-that-activates-dropdown');

dropdown_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //here do what you want to do when the button is clicked.
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use javascript events , some thing like this :

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn') // this button is a key to run what you want
var drp = document.getElementById('drp') // this is your dropdown list
btn.onclick = function()
{
    drp.style.display = 'block'
    // other codes . . .
}
```

Comment: ive put this is a .js file and embedded it in the html. ive given the appropriate list elements the id's but it's not working. I've iven the  <li> that contains the dropdown the id="btn" and ive given the dropdown <ul>  id="drp". could it be that it is not actually overriding the standard css value which is display:none?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using javascript.

Use the [`:target`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) selector

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/5TrJt)

Add an `id` and `href` for each target in the html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=" " title="">Home</a></li>
    <li id="Opleiding">
    <a title="" href="#Opleiding">Opleiding</a> 

            <!-- the dropdown -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Visie &amp; Beleid</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Opbouw Studieprogramma</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Competenties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Diploma</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Beroepen</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Onderwijsprogramma</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Organisatie</a></li>
        <li id="StagesenProjecten">
        <a href="#StagesenProjecten" title="">Stages en Projecten</a>

            <!-- another dropdown -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Stages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Projecten</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#home">Top</a></li>
    </ul>
```

in the css specify the style for the `:target`

```
nav > ul > li:target ul {
            display: block;
        }

nav > ul > li:hover ul {
            display: block;
        }
nav > ul > li > ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

Comment: I'm going to remember this thanks :). but the school assignment was to use specifically javascript for device specific interaction. So on an ipad you cant hover so I wanted to add an onclick to make the dropdown work on ipad.

Comment: @MohammedKareem also have a look at the ``:active`` selector. see this [Pure CSS Clickable Events Without :target](http://www.ryancollins.me/?p=1041)